# Substitute gives me different result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm working with Legendre polynomials (& associated ones). When I do the following calculation:

```
Table[Integrate[LegendreP[k, 0, Cos[η]] * Sin[η], {η, 0, Pi}], {k, 0, 10}]
```

I tried out one particular value of `k` to see the calculation time:

```
Timing[Integrate[LegendreP[k, 0, Cos[η]] * Sin[η], {η, 0, Pi}] /. k -> 0]
```

That is when I found this different result `/.` causes:
[image: results]

I do have a way to get around this issue, but I really want to know why the `Replace[]` can cause this indeterminate result and all the warning messages.

Thank you!

Comment: Ponder on the result of `Integrate[LegendreP[k, 0, Cos[η]] Sin[η], {η, 0, π}]`, and then consider `Limit[Integrate[LegendreP[k, 0, Cos[η]] Sin[η], {η, 0, π}], k -> 0]`.

Comment: Or `Timing[Integrate[LegendreP[k, 0, Cos[η]]*Sin[η] /. k -> 0, {η, 0, Pi}]]`

Comment: @J.M. I think you are right on the point. Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks.

Comment: If you figured out my hint, please consider writing an answer to your own question. ;)

Comment: @J.M. haha, I'll do that, but please tell me how to correctly type `\[Eta]` and `\[Pi]` in the code mode =P

Comment: In this case, I know the Unicode for them, but it might be easier for you to just copy the characters in your question, or use a character map program in your OS.

Comment: @J.M. wow! ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was given a hint by @J.M. (Thank you!)

The reason that I got `Indeterminate` and all the warning messages is because the order of calculation in this expression:

```
Integrate[LegendreP[k, 0, Cos[η]] * Sin[η], {η, 0, Pi}] /. k -> 0
```

This expression calculates the Integral of `LegendreP[k, 0, x]` from `-1` to `1` before replace the `k` with `0`.

So, in Mathematica, if we calculate the integral, this is the result:
[image]

And when replace `k` by `0` clearly will cause problem.

Lessons learned!

Comment: Nicely done. $\phantom{}$